# ElasticSearch - Search for complete phrase only

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create a search that will return me exactly what i requested.

For instance let's say i have 2 documents with a field named 'Val'

First doc have a value of 'a - Copy', second document is 'a - Copy (2)'

**My goal** is to search exactly the value 'a - Copy' and find only the **first** document in my returned results and not both of them with different similarity rankings

When i try most of the usual queries like:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": { 
      "Val": {
          "query": "a - copy",
          "type":  "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or:

```
GET /test/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "Val",
      "query": "a - copy"
    }
  }
}
```

I get both documents all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very good documentation for finding exact values in ES: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html

It shows you how to use the `term` filter and it mentions problems with `analyzed fields`, too.

To put it in a nutshell you need to run a `term` filter like this (I've put your values in):

```
GET /test/doc/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : { 
            "query" : {
                "match_all" : {} 
            },
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { 
                    "Val" : "a - copy"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work with analyzed fields. You won't get any results.

> To prevent this from happening, we need to tell Elasticsearch that
>   this field contains an exact value by setting it to be not_analyzed.

There are multiple ways to achieve that. e.g. [custom field mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#custom-field-mappings).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are getting that because your field is, most likely, `analyzed` and split into tokens.

You need an analyzer similar to this one

```
    "custom_keyword_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "keyword",
      "filter": "lowercase"
    }
```

which uses the `keyword` tokenizer and the `lowercase` filter (I noticed you indexed upper case letters, but expect to search with lowercase letters).

And then use a `term` filter to search your documents.